# How to redirect all traffic to the script ignoring folders with webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack-dev-server, pretty-urls

I have a SPA with pretty url navigation (`/link` instead of `#link`). It works fine as long as I start on the root and navigate around from there but if I go directly to `/link` in the browser I get `Cannot GET /link`.

How do I rewrite all requests to go to the main script file?

I've read through the webpack-dev-server docs but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, in `webpack.config.json` add the following:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```